# RuntimeError: cuDNN version incompatibility

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory, cudnn

I wrote an LSTM NLP classifier with PyTorch, in google colab and it worked well. Now, I run it on google colab **pro**, but I get this error:

> RuntimeError: cuDNN version incompatibility: PyTorch was compiled  against (8, 3, 2) but found runtime version (8, 0, 5). PyTorch already comes bundled with cuDNN. One option to resolving this error is to ensure PyTorch can find the bundled cuDNN.one possibility is that there is a conflicting cuDNN in LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

I have no idea how to fix this. I'm using GPU on colab pro.
I've tried this [link](https://jtuto.com/cudnn-error-when-runnung-pytorch-on-google-colab/) and it didn't work.
How I declared device:

```
DEVICE = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed via upgrading cuDNN to 8.4

reference (https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR/issues/716)

**if you are using google colab uae this command**

```
!pip install --upgrade torch torchvision
```